# Passing variable values from one script after executing the first script and we execute second script manually

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a requirement to achieve in shell script.

There are two scripts script1, script2. When I run the first script two variables are created and are having some values. It will finish its execution. (the values will be right here as the script finished executing right?)

Script2 will be executed again manually later on(not sure when this script will be executed, may 30 mins or even 1 day as we have to fix something after the script1 runs).

Now I wanted to get the variables which were created in script 1 into script 2. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you need a `sh`-compatible answer, or is a `bash`-only one acceptable? (Using both tags makes that ambiguous).

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy, Need the answer related to shell script. Sorry I was new to this scripting part.

Comment: There's not just one "shell script" language. `sh` and `bash` are two different (POSIX-compliant) shell languages, just as C and C++ are different compiled languages. (Or, rather, `sh` is a name guaranteed to provide an interpreter for a POSIX sh shell, but not guaranteed to support any features not in that standard -- it may be implemented by `ash`, `dash`, or others; `bash` is a specific shell with a bunch of extensions that are often helpful, but which also runs much slower than many of the baseline shells). If you use the bash tag, expect an answer that works in bash but not with `sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not** generate content to be `source`ed in or `eval`ed unless you're prepared to deal with the security issues involved with same.

It's much safer to write a NUL-delimited stream (the same format that Linux uses to expose environment variable contents in `/proc/*/environ`):

```
tempfile=$(mktemp vars.XXXXXX)
for varname in var1 var2; do
  printf '%s=%s\0' "$varname" "${!varname}"
done >"$tempfile"
mv -- "$tempfile" varfile  # this is an atomic operation, so you can't have a half-written varfile
```

...and then read it back:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' assignment; do
  [[ $assignment = *=* ]] || { printf 'ERROR: No = found in %q\n' "$assignment" >&2; continue; }
  var=${assignment%%=*}
  value=${assignment#*=}
  printf -v "$var" %s "$value"
done <varfile
```

Comment: Thanks Charles for your help! It helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Charles' answer is the correct one as this can lead to code injection, but if you don't care about security (*you should)*, then this will work.

Use source or "." and export the variables to a file

**script1.sh:**

```
var1='foo'
var2='bar'
cat > varfile <<-EOF
    var1="${var1}"
    var2="${var2}"
EOF
```

**script2.sh:**

```
. varfile
echo "${var1} ${var2}"
```

**output:**

```
$ ./script1.sh
$ ./script2.sh
foo bar
$
```

Comment: If using source or "." than you don't have to write to files, just use source for both scripts.

script1 
`#!/bin/bash
var1='foo'
var2='bar'
`
script2
`#!/bin/bash
echo $var1 $var2
`
And `. ./script1; . ./script2`

Comment: That would mean he needs to rerun script1 in order get the variables and he mentioned that script2 might need to be run 30 mins to a full day after

Comment: This is not a safe way to generate code. Consider if `var1=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''`; someone trying to dot in `varfile` would delete their home directory.

Comment: If you want to *safely* generate code that assigns two variables their existing values, then `declare -p var1 var2 >varfile`, or `printf '%q=%q\n' var1 "$var1" var2 "$var2" >varfile`

Comment: Hello @Nobody

Thank you, I tried this approach but the it is giving me an error as below. Created the file using first script and reading it using second script. It worked for the first time and after that it is giving me this error. Strange!

I tried grant chmod 777 permisions for this varfile but it still remains the same, no change in permissions for the file,


`script.sh: line 44: .: varfile: file not found`

Comment: Are you using full paths to the files? Also Charles' solution would probably be a better option for security and error handling

Comment: Thank you @Nobody with Full path worked it worked, but even if the files are in the same folder do we need to mention the full path? I was completely new to shell scripting so found the code posted easy, i will also implement the Charles code and check it out as we also need to consider the Security part and mark the answer as correct! .

Comment: It's usually best to have a full path to everything if possible; just makes code easier to maintain, port, and read, and you can of course use variables for the paths to files. You don't need it when in the same directory, but as you just saw even when you think you are it can be problematic.

Comment: @HarshaGNS, paths are resolved not relative to the active source file, but relative to the *current working directory* of the process that's opening them. So if you `cd /foo`, then `. something` will be looking for `/foo/something`, f/e. As another example, if the user is in `/tmp` and runs `/usr/local/bin/whatever`, then if `whatever` runs `. something`, it'll look for `/tmp/something`, not `/usr/local/bin/something`.

Comment: @HarshaGNS, btw, I *strongly* suggest that you not ever use `chmod 777`. It's that 3rd `7` that's harmful, because it means *anyone in the whole world* who can get into your system, even with the least-privileged user, can modify that file... which is also executable by every user, including yourself; so someone who breaks into even an unprivileged account like `nobody` can then modify a file that more-privileged accounts are running as a script.

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the suggested. I will take care of that